Why am I getting this error? Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 73
Here is my code. I tried all modifications to this code but I'm not able to resolve the problem. Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?
(* Function to convert an index to a permutation *)
PermutationFromIndex[index_, elements_List] := Module[
  {n = Length[elements], digits, factorialRepresentation, availableElements, permutation},
  
  (* Decrement the index by 1 to make it 0-based *)
  index = index - 1;
  
  (* Convert the index to factorial number system *)
  digits = IntegerDigits[index, MixedRadix[Table[i, {i, n - 1, 1, -1}]]];
  
  (* Pad the digits list to length n - 1 *)
  digits = PadLeft[digits, n - 1, 0];
  
  (* Initialize the available elements list *)
  availableElements = elements;
  
  (* Generate the permutation using the factorial representation *)
  permutation = Table[
    With[{d = digits[[i]]},
      (* Select the d-th element from the available elements *)
      availableElements = DeleteCases[availableElements, availableElements[[d + 1]], {1}, 1];
      availableElements[[d + 1]]
    ],
    {i, 1, n - 1}
  ];
  
  (* Append the remaining element to the permutation *)
  AppendTo[permutation, First@availableElements];
  
  permutation
]

(* Function to convert an index to a permutation for a range *)
PermutationFromIndexFromRange[index_, start_, end_] := 
  PermutationFromIndex[index, Range[start, end]]

(* Example usage *)
PermutationFromIndexFromRange[73, 1, 5]


You defined your function as PermutationFromIndex[index_,elements_List] then inside the module, you are doing index = index - 1;, you can't do this in Mathematica. Mathematica default is pass by value. So if you passed index, its value will be used, which in your case is a number. So you are trying to assign to raw object (a number). This is not allowed.

To workaround this, make new local variable inside your module, and use that. Like this  Module[{myIndex=index,...},...] and now you can change myIndex as you want inside the module. But you can't change index inside the module.
